# How can I stack multiple time series charts in R?

Tags: r

I am using R/RStudio. How do I stack charts? The current code I use is:

```
par(mfrow=c(3,1))
ts.plot(RSI_ts)
ts.plot(AWE_ts)
ts.plot(JOBS_ts)
```

which gives me three separate time series charts.

Ideally, what I want to achieve is the page 13 equivalent of this:
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/timeSeries/vignettes/timeSeriesPlot.pdf

But either use the ts.plot() function or alternatively plot() but then how do I put the three time series into a single variable?

Cheers

Comment: `ts.plot(RSI_ts, AWE_ts, JOBS_ts)` ?

Comment: Thanks but no, that puts all three time series into one chart. I want three separate charts but immediately one on top of the other.